# Do While, Do until all observation dates equal to today() sas proc sql

Tags: loops, date, macros, sas

I have to run a report every morning, but cannot do until all the tables that I am querying from have been updated for that day.

I want to make a macro that does not continue with sas processing until all of the tables have updated. There is one table with all of the tables in SSDM and date and time they are updated. For easier purposes,I will call this table Info and the col names are tablename and dateupdated. The tables I will be using are table1, table2 and table3 out of n tables.

```
%macro Updated;

proc sql;
create table Data_ready as
select 
tablename,
dateupdated,
case when dateupdated=today() then 'Ready'
 else 'Not Ready'
 end as 'Status'
from Info
where tablename in (table1, table2, ..., tablen)
quit;


%if count(Data_ready.Status = 'Ready') ne count(Data_ready.tablename) %then %do;
proc sql;
drop table work.Data_ready
;quit;
sleep(60*30,1);
%end;
%else %do;
proc print data=Data_ready;
run;
%end
%mend;
*here I will have the rest of the code to produce the report knowing that the information is up to date
```

Is there a way I can do this with a do while or do until ? I have been trying to figure out some kind of macro but am running into some problems with making sure all tables are updated before going forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does table WORK.INFO come from ?  Since it is in your WORK library, how does it get updated ?  Is this pseudo-code and you need to know how to query a data sets metadata ? Is SSDM a libname ?

Comment: I updated my code as I saw some errors, but the "info" table is just a list of tables and date and time they are updated in the given library. I need to know if the date listed in "Info" is today to know that it is updated and the code in the rest of the code can be executed with the up to date data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code (untested) that uses `DICTIONARY.TABLES` to examine the modification time stamp of a dataset, and counts how many of those correspond to `today()`. A try_limit is also used to prevent infinite waiting.

```
%macro wait_for_all_today (libname=);

  %local today_count all_count;
  %local try try_limit try_wait_s;
  %local rc;

  %let try = 0;
  %let try_limit = 10;
  %let try_wait_s = 60;

  %do %until (&today_count = &all_count or &try > &try_limit);
    %let try = %eval (&try + 1);
    %if &try > 1 %then %do;
      %let rc = %sysfunc(sleep(&try_wait_s, 1));
    %end;
    proc sql noprint;
      select count(*), sum(today()=datepart(moddate)) 
      into :all_count, :today_count
      from dictionary.tables
      where libname = "%sysfunc(upcase(&libname))"
        and memtype = "DATA"
      ;
    quit;

    %* at this point today_count and all_count 
    %* have values that will be used in the UNTIL evaluation;
  %end;

  %if &today_count ne &all_count %then %do;
    %put ERROR: Not all data sets in Library &libname were updated today. Waited a bunch of times;
    %abort cancel;
  %end;

%mend;
```